# How do I bind a member function template passing unspecified call wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I tried to compile the following example using VC11 and g++ 4.7.2:

```
#include <functional>

class X {
public:
  template <typename T>
  explicit X(T t)
  {
    std::bind(&X::invoke<T>, this, t)();
  }
private:
  template <typename T>
  void invoke(T t)
  {
    t();
  }
};

class Y {
  public:
    void foo() {
      //...
    }
};


int main() {
  Y y;
  X x(std::bind(&Y::foo, &y));
  return 0;
}
```

but it finished with errors. I'm not sure if it is reasonable to paste the whole compilers output but generally

vc11 says:

> error C2664: 'void std::_Pmf_wrap::operator ()(_Farg0 &,_V0_t) const' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void' to 'std::_Bind,Y *,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional   1152    1   ConsoleApplication1 (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP)

and g++:

> Compilation finished with errors:
>   source.cpp: In instantiation of 'X::X(T) [with T = std::_Bind(Y*)>]':
>   source.cpp:28:33:   required from here
>   source.cpp:8:9: error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind_helper(Y*)>), X* const, std::_Bind(Y*)>&>::type {aka std::_Bind(Y*)>)>(X*, std::_Bind(Y*)>)>}) ()'

Is there a way to solve this issue. It's very important for me, to save the main idea - a class that can be instantiated with any callable object (function object, function pointer or call wrapper returned by `std::bind()` function).

I would be grateful if someone help.

P.S. It compiles if I create an instance of `X`, passing function object or function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem seems to be the internal copying of its arguments performed by `std::bind`, with particular reference to `t`.

You may want to workaround it this way:

```
  template <typename T>
  explicit X(T t)
  {
      std::bind(&X::invoke<T>, this, std::placeholders::_1)(t);
      //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^
  }
```

This will also work, but you won't be allowed to make the result of `bind` outlive the argument `t` (otherwise, you would be passing a dangling reference to `invoke<T>()`):

```
  template <typename T>
  explicit X(T t)
  {
      std::bind(&X::invoke<T>, this, cref(t))();
      //                             ^^^^^^^
  }
```

---

**UPDATE:**

*The above solutions are workarounds that help for achieving what you are showing in your example. However, it emerged from the comments that your use case may be quite different (e.g. passing around the result of `bind` for later evaluation).*

As correctly pointed out by [Maxim Yegorushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412080/maxim-yegorushkin) in his answer, the conceptually correct solution consists in using a construct such as Boost's `protect`.

In case you do not want to use Boost, it is quite easy to define your own `protect()` function using C++11's variadic templates:

```
// Imitates boost::protect, but with variadic templates and perfect forwarding
namespace detail
{
    template<typename F>
    struct protect
    {
    private:

        F _f;

    public:

        explicit protect(F f): _f(f)
        {
        }

        template<typename... Ts>
        auto operator () (Ts&&... args) -> 
            decltype(_f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))
        {
            return _f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        }
    };
}

template<typename F>
detail::protect<F> protect(F&& f)
{
    return detail::protect<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Eventually, this is how you could use it in your class, as Maxim suggested:

```
class X
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    explicit X(T t)
    {
        auto pt = protect(t);
        std::bind(&X::invoke<decltype(pt)>, this, pt)();
    }
private:
    template <typename T>
    void invoke(T t)
    {
        t();
    }
};
```

Comment: It solves a somewhat different problem, in my opinion. The original bind expression is self-contained in a sense that it stores copies of all arguments, so that the arguments can be destroyed. Your solutions omit copying the functor and relies that it is still in scope and alive at the time of the call. Realistically, there is no point in creating a bind expression and then immediately calling it. Rather you want to pass the functor created by bind somewhere else and often delay calling till later.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Indeed. Still, this is an effective workaround for the OP's use case.

Comment: Not sure if that is his real use case. See my updated previous comment.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: I understood your comment. Based on the example the OP supplied, this provides a *workaround* (that's the word I used). I am not claiming it is a conceptually perfect solution. Especially with the first workaround I suggested, the OP is not forced to invoke the result of bind immediately; it can just copy the argument around separately. Again, I'm not claiming this solution is perfect, let alone better than yours, I'm just saying it provides a *workaround*. For instance, the OP might not want to use boost.

Comment: Thanks Andy, std::bind(&X::invoke<T>, this, cref(t))() solves my problem. It is also will be useful if I intend to start a thread in the ctor, binding invoke() method as threads entry point.

Comment: @user2102602: No, you shouldn't do that. As mentioned in the answer, you would create a dangling reference. Let me edit.

Comment: Oh, yes in my case if I bind it to a thread, then invoke() will get a reference_wrapper, containing dangling argument.

Answer (score 4):

I think they omitted an important bit of `boost::bind` when adopting it into `std::bind`, namely `boost::protect()`. Your code can be fixed like the following:

```
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>
// ...
X x(boost::protect(std::bind(&Y::foo, &y)));
```

Or, alternatively:

```
template <typename T>
explicit X(T t)
{
    auto tt = boost::protect(t);
    auto f = std::bind(&X::invoke<decltype(tt)>, this, tt);
    f();
}
```

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html

> Although the first argument is, by default, not evaluated, all other arguments are. Sometimes it is necessary not to evaluate arguments subsequent to the first, even when they are nested bind subexpressions. This can be achieved with the help of another function object, protect, that masks the type so that bind does not recognize and evaluate it. When called, protect simply forwards the argument list to the other function object unmodified.
>
> The header boost/bind/protect.hpp contains an implementation of protect. To protect a bind function object from evaluation, use protect(bind(f, ...)).

---

The upcoming [Effective C++11: Content and Status](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/effective-c11-content-and-status.html) by Scott Meyers is going to recommend *prefer lambdas to std::bind*. In C++11 you can simply do:

```
template <typename T>
explicit X(T t)
{
    auto f = [t, this]() { this->invoke(t); };
    f();
}
// ...

X x([&y](){ y.foo(); });
```

Comment: The upcoming Effective C++11: Content and Status is available as "Effective Modern C++".   Items 34 is "prefer lambdas to std::bind", and concludes "Lamda are more readable, more expressive ...".

Comment: @JeanDavy Was it not released a few months ago?

Comment: Oup's, yes it is. I worked with Java and Python these last months and so I neglected C++, now that I'm back to my first true love ;-), I just bought it.